# How do I send keys using Capybara with selenium web driver

Tags: ruby, selenium, automation, capybara

I know capybara uses native, do I need to install a gem for this?

I am trying to press enter after typing in a search box

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If using capybara 2.5 you can do

```
input = find_field 'id, name, label of search box'
input.send_keys 'text to send', :enter
```

If using capybara < 2.5 with selenium it would be

```
input.native.send_keys 'text to send', :enter
```

Comment: def search(keyword)
    searchbox = find(:css, "#q")
    searchbox.send_keys keyword, :enter
  end                                                                                                                                  require 'rails_ui_helper'

describe 'Search' do

  it 'should serarch for article' do
    @home_page.home
    @home_page.search("article name")
  end
end

Comment: 1) Search should serarch for article
     Failure/Error: @home_page.search("article name")
     NotImplementedError:
       NotImplementedError
     # /Users/techops/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/capybara-2.5.0/lib/capybara/driver/node.rb:54:in `send_keys'
     # /Users/techops/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/capybara-2.5.0/lib/capybara/node/element.rb:224:in `block in send_keys'
     # /Users/techops/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/capybara-2.5.0/lib/capybara/node/base.rb:84:in `synchronize'
     # /Users/techops/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/capybara-

Comment: I still get the NotImplementedError

Comment: Are you sure you're actually using the selenium driver and not using rack-test (which doesn't support JS and therefore also doesn't support JS key events)???  If you are actually using selenium there would be /lib/capybara/selenium/node.rb somewhere in the stacktrace

Comment: I use selenium and am still getting the `NotImplemented` error when trying to send keys to an input field

Comment: @sixty4bit then you aren't using a recent version of capybara (2.5+) or your test isn't actually using selenium (no js: true set on the test or other method of selecting the selenium driver for that test)

Comment: @TomWalpole oops! you're right, forgot the `js: true`